# PHP routing system

Tags: php, regex, mvc, url-routing, symfony2

I made a routing system for PHP inspired by Symfony's router composed of a few classes.

First I am using Symfony's HTTP Foundations component.
Then, I am emulating the classes in the routing component but with almost completely my own implementation (I did copy few lines).

The whole system is not simple so I won't be making it the focus of the question, though, this is the [GitHub link](https://github.com/spasenovski/coolRouter/tree/989129b31cfa8618b1dc30e140ac683228d9411a), and I would be grateful for a full review (rip me apart).

I will provide the class that matches and parses the routes and I would like to know what I can improve.

There is a parser class:

```
<?php

namespace Routing;

/**
    * Takes an instance of Routing\Route object
    * Extracts the variables from wildcards
    * Calculates a regex that can be used to match routes with urls
*/

class RouteParser
{   
    /**
        * Asks for a route, extracts info that can be used later
        *
        * @param Route               Routing/Route
        *
        * @return array              Array with parsed values 
    */
    public function parseRoute(Route $route)
    {
        $variables = array();

        $parsed = self::parse($route->getPath());

        return ['variables' => $parsed['variables'], 'matcherReg' => $parsed['regex']];
    }

    /**
        * Takes a string pattern, matches it with regexes
        *
        * @param string              The pattern 
        *
        * @return array              Array with parsed values 
    */
    private static function parse($pattern)
    {   
        $matches = '';
        $variables = array();
        $pos = 0;
        $reg = '#'; //It seems that regex must start and end with a delimiter
        $nextText = '';

        if($pattern == '/')
        {   
            $reg = '#^[\/]+$#';

            return ['variables' => '', 'regex' => $reg];
        }

        //Check if generated regexes are stored, if so it skips the whole process
        if(apc_exists($pattern))
        {
            $cacheI = apc_fetch($pattern);
            return $cacheI;
        }

        //Extracts the variables enclosed in {}
        preg_match_all('#\{\w+\}#', $pattern, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE | PREG_SET_ORDER);
        
        //Puts each variable in array 
        //Uses the text before and after to create a regex for the rest of the pattern - $precedingText, $nextText
        //If no wildcard is detected in the path it splits it into segments and compiles are regex
        foreach ($matches as $match) 
        {   
            $varName = substr($match[0][0], 1, -1);
            $precedingText = substr($pattern, $pos, $match[0][1] - $pos);
            $pos = $match[0][1] + strlen($match[0][0]);
            $nxt = $pos - strlen($pattern);
            if($nxt == 0) $nxt = strlen($pattern);

            $nextText = substr($pattern, $nxt);
            
            $precSegments = explode('/', $precedingText);
            $precSegments = array_splice($precSegments, 1);

            //Pulls a regex from the preeceding segment, each variable segment is replaced with '\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+'
            if(strlen($precedingText) > 1)
            {       
                foreach($precSegments as $key => $value) {  
                    $reg .= '\/';
                    $reg .= $value; 
                }

                $reg .= '[a-zA-Z0-9]+';  
            }
            else
            {
                $reg .= '\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+';
            }

            $nextText = str_replace('/', '\/', $nextText);
            
            if(is_numeric($varName)) {
                throw new \Exception('Argument cannot be a number');
            }

            if (in_array($varName, $variables)) {
                throw new \Exception(sprintf('More then one occurrence of variable name "%s".', $varName));
            }

            $variables[] = $varName;    
        }
        
        //If no variable names, wildcards are found in pattern : /hello/static/path it will replace it with \/hello\/static\/path
        if(count($matches) < 1 && $pattern != '/')
        {   
            $reg .= str_replace('/', '\/', $pattern);
        }
        
        $reg = $reg . $nextText;
        $reg .= '#';
        
        apc_store($pattern, ['variables' => $variables, 'regex' => $reg]);

        return ['variables' => $variables, 'regex' => $reg];
    }
}
```

and the matcher class:

```
<?php 

namespace Routing;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class Matcher 
{   
    /**
        * @var RouteCollection
    */
    private $routes;

    /**
        * @var Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request
    */
    private $request;
    
    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param RouteCollection $routes                   A RouteCollection instance
     * @param Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request  A Symfony Request
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request, RouteCollection $collection)
    {
        $this->routes = $collection;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function matchRequest()
    {   
        $return = array();

        foreach ($this->routes->all() as $name => $route)
        {       
            if(preg_match($route['parsed']['matcherReg'], $this->request->getPathInfo()))   
            {
                if(!in_array($this->request->getMethod(), $route['route']->getHttpMethods()))
                {
                    throw new \Exception(sprintf('Method "%s" not allowed', $this->request->getMethod()), 1);
                }
                //var_dump($this->request);
                return [
                    '_vars' => $route['parsed']['variables'],
                    '_controller' => $route['route']->getController(),
                    '_varValues' => self::realVariables($route['route']->getPath(), $this->request->getPathInfo())
                ];
            }
        }
        
        throw new \Exception(sprintf('Route for "%s" not found', $this->request->getPathInfo()), 1);
    }

    private static function realVariables($routePath, $pathInfo)
    {
        $i = 0;
        $poss = [];
        $vars = [];

        $routeSegs = explode('/', $routePath);
        $segs = explode('/', $pathInfo);

        foreach ($routeSegs as $key => $value) {
            if(preg_match('#\{\w+\}#', $value))
            {   
                $poss[] = $i;
                
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $segs = array_splice($segs, 1);

        foreach ($poss as $key => $index) {
            $vars[] = $segs[$index];
        }

        return $vars;
    }
}
```

They are [used in an `index.php`](https://github.com/spasenovski/coolRouter/blob/989129b31cfa8618b1dc30e140ac683228d9411a/web/index.php), as in this excerpt:

```
<?php

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();    
$response = new Response();


$routes->add('name', new Route(['GET'], 'hi/{p1}/cicki/{p2}', function($p1, $p2) use ($response) {
        $response->setContent($p1 . ' - ' . $p2);
}));

try
{
    $urlMatcher = new Matcher($request, $routes);
    $rez = $urlMatcher->matchRequest();
} 
catch(Exception $e) {echo $e;} 

call_user_func_array($rez['_controller'], $rez['_varValues']);
$response->send();
```

So it basically takes a path pattern, with static strings or parameters enclosed in {}, extracts the parameters and generates a regex to be compared to the URL. If it matches then it returns the parameters, their values, the controller (a PHP closure) and it doesn't yet support optional parameters.

Edit: You may notice that I am caching my regexes with apc, so I would like to underline that after a route removal I am not invalidating the cache(A feature I still have to work on).

Answer (score 2):

I apologize that nobody has reviewed this code in six years since it was posted. Perhaps you have learned a few things since then but hopefully the review below will still be helpful.

### Array syntax

I like that the code takes advantage of the PHP 5.4 feature of short array syntax, though not in every array declaration - e.g. in `RouteParser::parseRoute()` the first declaration uses the legacy format while the `return` statement includes the shorthand format. There is nothing wrong with this but if this was my code then I would make it consistent.

### Docblock format

While it may not exactly have a standard the widely accepted common [docblock syntax](https://docs.phpdoc.org/guide/references/phpdoc/basic-syntax.html#what-is-a-docblock) contains no indentation for inner lines. Most of the docblocks used in the code contain extra indentation levels  - e.g.

> ```
> /**
>     * Takes an instance of Routing\Route object
>     * Extracts the variables from wildcards
>     * Calculates a regex that can be used to match routes with urls
> */
> ```

Typically those would not have extra indentation - so the asterisks on each line are aligned vertically - e.g.

```
/**
 * Takes an instance of Routing\Route object
 * Extracts the variables from wildcards
 * Calculates a regex that can be used to match routes with urls
 */
```

### New lines for all blocks

Adhering to a standard is not required but it does help anyone reading the code. Many PHP developers follow PSRs like [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/). While it wasn't approved until 2019, [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) replaced [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) which was approved in 2012.

I have grown accustom to starting class and method blocks on a new line (per [PSR-12 section 4.4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#44-methods-and-functions)) but doing so for other control structures like loops and conditionals feels a bit excessive and is not in-line with [PSR-12 section 5](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#5-control-structures).

> There MUST be one space between the closing parenthesis and the opening brace

### Unused variable

In the method `RouteParser::parseRoute()` the variable `$variables` is declared but never used. It can be eliminated without effecting anything. This will help avoid confusion for anyone reading the code in the future - which may include yourself.

### Method length and simplification

The method `RouteParser::parse()` is a bit on the long side. Some of the variables declared declared at the beginning are not used in the early returns and could be declared after those conditional returns - e.g. `$matches`, `$variables`, `$pos`, `$nextText`.  Removing new lines before opening braces will decrease the length of that method.

Instead of splicing together substrings, a simpler approach would be to use `str_replace()` to simply replace what needs to be replaced. The sample below uses positive look-behind and positive look ahead to not capture the curly brackets - this allows those matches to be added directly to the list of variables.

```
$variables = array();
$reg = '#' . str_replace('/', '\\\\/', $pattern) . '#';
preg_match_all('#(?!\{)\w+(?=\})#', $pattern, $matches);
if (count($matches)) {
    $counts = array_count_values($matches[0]);
    $duplicates = array_filter($counts, function ($count) {
        return $count > 1;
    });
    if (count($duplicates)) {
        throw new \Exception(sprintf('More than one occurrence of variable(s): "%s".', implode(',',array_keys($duplicates))));
    }
    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
        $reg = str_replace("{" . $match . "}", '[a-zA-Z0-9]+', $reg);
        $variables[] = $match;
    }
}
apc_store($pattern, ['variables' => $variables, 'regex' => $reg]);

return ['variables' => $variables, 'regex' => $reg];
```

And the `foreach` loop could also be replaced with a single call to [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) though it would need to add the matches to `$variables` within the callback and some may find that impure for a functional approach.

```
$reg = preg_replace_callback('#\{\w+\}#', function($matches) use (&$variables) {
    $varName = substr($matches[0], 1, -1);
    if(is_numeric($varName)) {
        throw new \Exception('Argument cannot be a number');
    }
    if (in_array($varName, $variables)) {
        throw new \Exception(sprintf('More then one occurrence of variable name "%s".', $varName));
    }
    $variables[] = $varName;
    return '[a-zA-Z0-9]+';
}, $reg);
```

It seems that when the path is `'hi/{p1}/cicki/{p2}'` then the regex pattern returned is `'#\\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\/cicki\\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+#'` (see [this demo](https://3v4l.org/7as7Z))- it seems like that should contain the `'hi'` at the beginning but maybe you have a reason to remove that.